# Get custom attributes of enum value

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, windows-runtime

In a WinRT .NET application (C#) I want to get the custom attributes, that are defined on an enum value. Take the following enum for example:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Display(Name="Foo")]
    EnumValue1,

    [Display(Name="Bar")]
    EnumValue2
}
```

Now in "normal" .NET I know that I'm able to obtain the custom attributes of an enum value with `enumValue.GetType().GetMember(enumValue.ToString())`.

Unfortunately, in WinRT .NET the `GetMember()` method isn't available on the Type class.
Any suggestions how to go with this?

=====================================================

Thanks to Marc below, I found the **answer**!
The following code works to get a specific custom attribute from an enum value in .NET 4.5 WinRT:

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Enum enumValue)
        where T : Attribute
    {
        return enumValue
            .GetType()
            .GetTypeInfo()
            .GetDeclaredField(enumValue.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttribute<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do't prefix yur titles with "WinRT C#: " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Thats not possible. The Type.GetMember is still present in .Net 4.5!

Comment: @logicnp: The WinRT API is a subset of the full .NET API.

Comment: No, it's not defined on the Type class in the System namespace. Configuration: Windows Consumer Preview, VS11 Beta, Assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.dll

Comment: @JonSkeet: My bad! However, except via Intellisense/compile-time errors, how does one know if a API is present in WinRT or not. The API documentation page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx does not have a filter for WinRT like it does for Silverlight.

Comment: @logicnp: There's a separate set of documentation for WinRT at the moment, I believe. Whether they merge it into the main .NET documentation after release or not is a different matter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than looking for *members*, you should perhaps look specifically for fields. If that isn't available on the `Type` in WinRT, add `using System.Reflection;` and use `type.GetTypeInfo()` and look on there too, as various reflection facets are moved to the type-info.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I complemented my question above with the answer.